# How can I get a list of all permissions for a certain file system object for a certain user or group using?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices, system.security

I do this at C# winh .NET4.
It is easy to get the *current* user's credentials for any file or folder ([like this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/2a621122-6bf3-48bb-88a9-d121ee5310dd)). 
But the problem is that to get a collection of permissions (Read, Read Attributes, Write, etc.) for **any given** user or group, and I can not find a solution.
The files and folders is located in network share resource. Users and groups is Active Directory based.
It is wery easy to manage accounts with System.DirectoryServices. But permissions on file system objects is not in Active Directory, and that problem.

I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: Might be better suited for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I talking about .NET coding, serverfauit not suitable